# Using jQuery to change input button text back after a few seconds

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm using a form and jQuery to make a quick change on a web site.  I would like to change the button text to 'Saved!' then change it back to Update after a few seconds so the user can change the value again.  Of course they can hit the now 'Saved!' button again, but it doesn't look nice.

```
$("form.stock").submit(function(){
    // Example Post
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), { id: '123', stock: '1' });
    $(this).find(":submit").attr('value','Saved!');
    // This doesn't work, but is what I would like to do
    setTimeout($(this).find(":submit").attr('value','Update'), 2000);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First argument to setTimeout is function. So wrap your code inside an anonymous function and you are good to go.

```
$("form.stock").submit(function(){
    // Example Post
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), { id: '123', stock: '1' });
    var submit = $(this).find(":submit").attr('value','Saved!'); //Creating closure for setTimeout function. 
    setTimeout(function() { $(submit).attr('value','Update') }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

I am not able to test this code right now. Let me know if it doesn't work.

**EDIT:** As suggested by redsquare, it makes sense to create closure from the submit button itself.

Comment: no need to run the submit selector twice, you can put that in a var to use within the setTimeout

Answer (score 5):

If it's actually a "button" tag then to change it you would use.

```
$('#button_id').html('New Text');
```

Of course if you're preforming this onClick for that button then you could easily just pass (this) into the function as an object and $(this).html('New Text'); instead.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest, perhaps, a different (in my opinion better) interface to give feedback than changing the text of the button.  You could use [jGrowl](http://www.stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html) or the [dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7/Dialog) widget to display a message via a callback from the post method.

```
$("form.stock").submit(function(){
    $.post(
        $(this).attr('action'),
        { id: '123', stock: '1' },
        function() { $.jGrowl("Your update was successfully saved."); }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to wrap the action in a function:

```
setTimeout(function(){$(this).find(":submit").attr('value', 'Update')}, 2000);
```

Comment: I think 'this' inside the setTimeout anonymous function won't work correctly. One needs to use closure to capture 'this'.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form.stock").submit(function(){
    var $form = $(this);
    $.post( $form.attr('action'), { id: '123', stock: '1' } );
    var $submit = $form.find(":submit").attr('value','Saved!');
    window.setTimeout(function() {
         $submit.attr('value','Update') 
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```