# javascript for changing submit button text after click and back again

Tags: jquery, button, text, submit

I am using Gravity Forms and would like to change their submit button text to read "processing..." after onclick. Gravity Forms has told me to use some custom javascript in the heading.php file to make this happen. The following script was given (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071012/using-jquery-to-change-input-button-text-back-after-a-few-seconds) this link to point me the right direction but I am still learning and need some help! Can someone please break this code down for me a bit?

```
$("form.stock").submit(function()
{
    var $form = $(this);
    $.post( $form.attr('action'), { id: '123', stock: '1' } );
    var $submit = $form.find(":submit").attr('value','Saved!');
    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        $submit.attr('value','Update') 
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

What is form.stock referring to? And- id: '123' stock: '1' referring to?

And lastly, what does (this) do? - `var $form = $(this);`

I would appreciate your kindness - I know these are some basic questions that I should know!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("form.stock") // <-- this finds forms with class=stock
    .submit(function() { // <-- binds submit handler to them
    var $form = $(this);  //<-- this caches current form that's triggered event handler
       // ajax post to the current form's action attribute
       $.post($form.attr('action'), {
           id: '123',  // <-- these are the data passed back to your server
           stock: '1'
       });
       //  find's submit button and changes value to 'Saved!'
       var $submit = $form.find(":submit").attr('value', 'Saved!');
       window.setTimeout(function() {
           // after 2000ms update value back to 'Update'
           $submit.attr('value', 'Update')
       }, 2000);          
       return false; // <-- stops any event bubbling and default action of form submit
});​
```

Though you should really be doing the text change inside of success function.. That way only of the post was successful, it will change.

```
$("form.stock").submit(function() { 
    var $form = $(this);            
       $.post($form.attr('action'), function(){ 
          // these are now in the success function.. so these will only occur if ajax is successful
          var $submit = $form.find(":submit").attr('value', 'Saved!');
          window.setTimeout(function() {
              // after 2000ms update value back to 'Update'
              $submit.attr('value', 'Update')
          }, 2000);
       });        
    return false; // <-- stops any event bubbling and default action of form submit
});​
```

Comment: Great. Thank you! If I do not need to pass any data - just want the text to change in the submit button - can I rid of the 
'$.post($form.attr('action'), {
           id: '123',  // <-- these are the data passed back to your server
           stock: '1'
       });
'
all together? Do I need those 3 lines?

Comment: @user1877181, if you don't want to pass any data.. you can just send an empty {} or remove it.. so `$.post($form.attr('action'))`.. or `$.post($form.attr('action'),{});`.. though you should be doing those text changes inside the success function

Answer (score 1):

### What is form.stock referring to

A `<form>` element with `class=stock` as a jQuery selector.  If you have:

```
<form class="stock">
```

In your HTML, then `$("form.stock")` selects it.  `.submit` binds a function to the "submit" event for it.

### And- id: '123' stock: '1'

This is to create an HTTP POST request with this data.  In GET form, it would be a URL like this:

```
/action/?id=123&stock=1
```

The example probably just picked the values `123` and `1` arbitrarily to illustrate the example.  You should probably get those values from the form somehow.

### `$form = $(this)`

This simply assigns the result of the method call `$(this)` to a variable.

`$` is actually a jQuery method.  Essentially, `$(this)` calls a function on the argument `this`.  Calling functions is relatively expensive and eats up resources.  However, using a variable does not, so much.  It's more efficient to do this:

```
$form = $(this);
$form.one();
$form.two();
$form.three();
```

Instead of this:

```
$(this).one();
$(this).two();
$(this).three();
```

The former only has 4 method calls, but the latter has 6.

Don't be confused: `$form` is just a variable name.  It could be called `aform`, `form`, `x`, or any other valid name.

Comment: This is code I have implemented in header.php:
'<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$("form.buttontext") // <-- this finds forms with class=buttontext
 .submit(function() {  // <-- binds submit handler to them
  var $form = $(this); //<-- this caches current form that's triggered event handler        
  $.post($form.attr('action'), function(){ 
   var $submit = $form.find(":submit").attr('value', 'Processing');
   window.setTimeout(function() {
    $submit.attr('value', 'Register Now')
   }, 5000);
  });        
  return false; 
 });​
</script>'

Comment: The first time or 2 viewing page, the form button took on the css characteristics of the class "buttontext" for a first few seconds of page view and then changed back to original css. So something happened! But, no text change, however. And nothing happens after I click on the submit button, it was only when first visited the page. Now it's not doing it at all. 
Do I need to rid of the class in the stylesheet? Can/should I use form ID instead?  If I can tie the submit function to a class - shouldn't I be able to apply an "onclick" function simply through css?

Comment: @user1877181 it sounds like you should accept an answer here and create a separate question.

Comment: Will do. Thank you for the assistance so far!